# Compact if statement C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I just would like to be sure that I can write a compact if with a or condition in the following way:

```
const ST c_is = ((kg==0) || (kg==nktot)) ? 0 : 10;
```

The purpose is to set `c_is` to 0 if `kg` is 0 or `nktot` and 10 otherwise.

Could you confirm me that it is ok?

Comment: `(!kg || (kg==nktot)) ? 0 : 10` -> `(kg && (kg!=nktot)) ? 10 : 0` -> `(kg && (kg!=nktot)) * 10`

Comment: when you are not 100% sure what some code does you should write a test to confirm. (When you are 100% sure then you are most likely wrong and need a test even more)

Comment: Definitely could be answered by writing tests. And you would learn more that way.

Comment: You can make it more compact by removing all those parentheses; they're not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's ok.

From the most readable to the most obscure:

```
// give more meaningful names, as it is only you know what these ids mean
constexpr ST set_is(ST kg) 
{
    if (kg == 0 || kg == nktot)
        return 0;
    return 10;
}

constexpr ST c_is = set_is(kg);
```

```
constexpr ST c_is = ((kg==0) || (kg==nktot)) ? 0 : 10;
```

```
constexpr ST c_is = [=] {
    if (kg == 0 || kg == nktot)
        return 0;
    return 10;
}();
```

```
constexpr ST c_is = (kg !=0 && kg !=nktot) * 10;
```

Comment: Sorry I've realised I've essentially duplicated your last expression. Have an upvote for good feelings.

Comment: @Bathsheba absolutely no worries. And I've realised I've duplicated a comment with my last expression. Have an upvote too for good feelings 

Answer (score 1):

You can do it branchlessly with

```
10 * !!kg * (kg != nktot)
```

Although there is nothing wrong with the expression you present, and my way might be considered a premature optimisation, or only slightly easier to read than James Joyce's Finnegans Wake.

Answer (score 0):

> The purpose is to set c_is to 0 if kg is 0 or nktot and 10 otherwise.
>
> Could you confirm me that it is ok?

It is ok.